# SQL Server CTE error: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, common-table-expression

I wrote a CTE code that parses out delimited strings (delimiter can be whatever) into a table. So "`MI,TX,WI`"  would be parsed into a table with 3 rows.

It works as long as I do not use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as the string input that I want to parse.

I want to know how I can get it to work with `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (or at very least `VARCHAR(MAX)`?

THIS WORKS except for comment if you change that you get this error:

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column
>   "b" of recursive query "cte".

```
--- change this to NVARCHAR(MAX) and it fails
DECLARE @DelimitedString NVARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @Delimiter NVARCHAR(10) 
SET @Delimiter = '--'

SET @DelimitedString= '123--456--7890, 234--456--7890'

-- do here instead of in every loop below
DECLARE @DelimiterLength AS TINYINT
SET @DelimiterLength = len(@Delimiter) 

;with cte as 
( 
    select 0 a, 1 b  
    union all 
    select b, charindex(@Delimiter, @DelimitedString, b) + len(@Delimiter)      
    from cte where b > a 
)   
select LTRIM(RTRIM(
    SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 
        a,                  
        case when b > @DelimiterLength then b-a-@DelimiterLength else len(@DelimitedString) - a + 1 end
    )--END SUBSTRING
))--end LTRIM/RTRIM
value         
from cte where a > 0
```

I understand what the error means in a standard, the columns in the UNION datatypes have to match.  I do not see how to fix the issue here.

I want it to work with however long of a string we need because I do not know if the usage will be limited to strings of 4000 characters or not.

Comment: Try casting b as an `int` in the top half of the cte.

Comment: There are some better ways to split strings than ctes. Here is a whole article dedicated to various splitters and how they stack up performance wise. No need to reinvent the wheel here. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHARINDEX()` returns a `BIGINT` when used with a `VARCHAR(MAX)` rather than an `INT` so you need the anchor types to also be `BIGINT`:

```
;with cte as ( 
    select cast(0 as bigint) a, cast(1 as bigint) b
```